# Disabled required validator still causes validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net, validation

I disable validator in jquery using validatorEnable (also tried with .Enabled) setting to false the error message dissapears but still the form isn't valid for that validator.

HTML:

```
<tr>
    <td class="text-right" style="width: 574px">
<asp:Label ID="usernameLabel" runat="server" Text="Username: "></asp:Label>
    </td>
    <td style="width: 181px">
<asp:TextBox ID="usernameTxt" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    </td>
    <td>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="usernameRequiredValidator" runat="server" ControlToValidate="usernameTxt" ErrorMessage="Username is required."></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        <br />
        <asp:CustomValidator ID="usernameExistsValidator" runat="server" ControlToValidate="usernameTxt" ErrorMessage="This username already exists." OnServerValidate="usernameExistsValidator_ServerValidate"></asp:CustomValidator>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Line below disables the validator the error message disappears.

```
ValidatorEnable($("[id*=usernameExistsValidator]")[0], false);
```

Check to make sure which validator is invalid:

```
foreach (BaseValidator validator in Page.Validators)
            {
                if (validator.Enabled && !validator.IsValid)
                {
                    // Put a breakpoint here
                    string clientID = validator.ClientID;
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(clientID + "is invalid.");
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ValidatorEnable` function only disables the validator on the client side.  The code that you are using to "Check to make sure which validator is invalid" is checking the validators on the server side.

Whatever condition you are using to disable to validator on the client side, you need to recreate it on the server side before running your validation routine.  For example, if you are calling

```
//Disable validator if user name textbox is empty
ValidatorEnable($("[id*=usernameExistsValidator]")[0], $("#usernameTxt").val().length > 0);
```

then on the server side you should write

```
//Disable validator if user name textbox is empty
this.usernameExistsValidator.Enabled = (this.usernameTxt.Text.Length > 0)
```

...before the validation is executed.